# Displaying JSON variable in RoR view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, object, model-view-controller, attributes

I'm trying to display json in a view that I've put in this variable '@yearbook':

```
def list
        file = File.open("#{Rails.root}/lib/service.json", "r")
        service = file
        service = service.read
        service = JSON.parse(service)
        @yearbook = service
    end
```

In my view file, I go through every '@yearbook' element and simply display it like so:

```
<% @yearbook.each do |item| %>
    <tr>
      <p><%= item %></p>
    </tr>
```

And this is what I get from the view on my browser (which is normal):

```
{"name"=>"...", "description"=>"..."}
{"name"=>"...", "description"=>"..."}
...
```

Now I don't understand how I can specify to the view to display me the "name" and "description" attributes instead of the formatted json object, making it look more like this:

```
name: ..., description: ...

name: ..., description: ... and so on...
```

Hope it's clear, cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like below :

```
<% @yearbook.each do |item| %>
  <tr>
    <p>
      <%= "name:" "#{item["name"]}" %>
      <%= "description:" "#{item["description"]}" %>
    </p>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Please upvote and accept my answer if it solves your problem, Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for answer, the exact code you gave me didn't work, but writing:  <p><%= item["name"] %></p>  (same for description) showed them which solves my problem.

Comment: @HCKRMVT , could you upvote if so my answer helped, i dint mean to copy paste it was my assumption per your question

Comment: refer updated answer semicolon ":" should be inside "name", copy paste this answer , it should work :)